# Is possible to rescue Alvin from the reverend?

Tags: the-witcher

I had the impression that the kid would have been much better living with the witch. Is possible to do something about this, or is a static aspect of the storyline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a static aspect of storyline. Interactions with Alvin is a part of plot of future chapters and Alvin himself is a major character.